# LIMIT do SQL retorna sempre os mesmos 3 últimos registros

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com um problema em um select. Tenho a seguinte tabela

```
id   id_de      id_para      mensagem           
---  ---------  -----------  -----------
1    10         20           Oi David.
2    20         10           Oi José
3    10         20           Tudo bem?
4    20         10           Sim, e com vc?
5    10         20           Estou ótimo?
```

Onde id é o identificador de cada mensagem, id_de é o id de quem está enviando a mensagem e id_ para é o id de quem está recebendo a mensagem.

Meu select é:

```
$select = BD::conn()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mensagem` WHERE (`id_de`= ? AND `id_para` = ?) OR (`id_de` = ? AND `id_para` = ?) LIMIT 3");
            $select->execute(array($_SESSION['id_user'], $id, $id, $_SESSION['id_user']));
```

Mas o problema é se eu enviar mais mensagens de um usuário para outro, ele sempre vai fazer o select das mesmas 3 mensagens. Se eu tirar o LIMIT do Select, ele retorna todas as mensagens corretamente.

Por favor se alguém puder me ajudar, serei grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto acontece pq o LIMIT vai retornar apenas os 3 primeiros registros.

Você pode dar um `order by id desc`, mas vai trazer de trás pra frente. Essa é a maneira mais fácil de resolver seu problema.

Para resolver o problema da ordem eu sugiro o seguinte:

- Faça sua query e use o `order by id desc` conforme te orientei.
- Transforme esta query num sub select. Este sub select você ordena por id novamente.

É feio, mas vai resolver seu problema.

Comment: Resolveu mais ou menos minha questão, porque ele exibiu as mensagems ao contrário, assim:

Estou ótimo
Sim, e com vc?
Tudo bem?
Oi José
Oi David.

No caso eu queria que fosse assim: 
Oi David.
Oi José
Tudo bem?
 Sim, e com vc?
= Estou ótimo?

Comment: Veja se meu edit ajuda